# How to avoid try_into().unwrap() conversions with loop indices?

Tags: rust

Is there a better way to use `i` and `j` for-in variables that avoids the use of `std::convert::TryInto` and `return vec![i.try_into().unwrap(),j.try_into().unwrap()];` for dealing with the usize and i32 conversion problem between what is expected as a result and the actual value type of these variables?

The use of the module and the `try_into()` and `unwrap()` functions was because of the compiler error suggestion. But I want to know if there is another way to cast or convert numeric values.

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

impl Solution {
    pub fn two_sum(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
       let mut current = 0;
       for i in 0..nums.len() - 1 {
           for j in 1..nums.len(){
               if j != i {
                   current = nums[i] + nums[j];
                   if current == target {
                       return vec![i.try_into().unwrap(),j.try_into().unwrap()];
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       vec![] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why return `Vec<i32>` instead of `Vec<usize>`?

Comment: This is a solution from a TwoSum problem of LeetCode https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/ and that is the function signature.

Comment: Personally, that function signature is just wrong. You should pretty much always use `usize` for indices. Seems like they're using `i32` because it's the equivalent of `int`, but that's pretty wrong in C++ too (should be `size_t`).

Comment: But yeah, absent that, `.try_into().unwrap()` is the most idiomatic way.

Comment: "But I want to know if there is another way to cast or convert numeric values." - yes, you can use `i as usize` and `j as usize` respectively, which is more readable and, I'd argue, more idiomatic.

Comment: @user4815162342 Please don't encourage people to switch from `try_into()` to `as`, particularly not beginners. There's a reason the compiler's help messages don't suggest using `as`. I'd argue that `as` is *not* idiomatic: it's short, yes, but its brevity is a footgun. It silently corrupts out-of-range values, which is quite un-Rust-like. What's actually idiomatic is using `into()` for lossless conversions and `try_into().unwrap()` for lossy ones.

Comment: I wish Rust had some `wrapping_into()` methods or similar to replace `as`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `i as i32` syntax, but that can cause silent overflow if `nums.len() > i32::MAX`

where `i32::MAX = 2_147_483_647` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/i32/constant.MAX.html

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn two_sum(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
        nums.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .find_map(|(i, &x)| {
                nums.iter()
                    .enumerate()
                    .find(|(j, &y)| *j != i && (x + y) == target)
                    .map(|(j, _)| vec![i as i32, j as i32])
            })
            .unwrap_or_default()
    }
}
```

Comment: I fear that putting `as` in an answer will tempt people to use it. Panicking is good, better than silent data corruption; the problem with `as` is that it *doesn't* panic.